# Does an expectation for a Markov chain simplify like this?

Tags: probability, expected-value, markov-process

Let $x_0 \sim N(\mu_0,\Sigma_0)$, where $\mu_0 \in \mathbb R^n$ and $\Sigma_0 \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$. Then, for $k = 0,\dots,N-1$, let $$x_{k+1} = Ax_k$$ for $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$. Next, define $$E_{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_{N}}[x_0] = \int_{\mathbb R^n} \int_{\mathbb R^n} \cdots \int_{\mathbb R^n} x_0 p(x_0,x_1,\dots,x_N) \text{d}x_N \dots \text{d}x_1 \text{d}x_0$$ and $$E_{x_0}[x_0] = \int_{\mathbb R^n} x_0 p(x_0) \text{d}x_0$$ Is it true that $$E_{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_{N}}[x_0] = E_{x_0}[x_0]$$ It would seem to me that the answer is yes. First, the sequence $x_0 \to x_1 \to \cdots \to x_N$ forms a Markov chain, such that the joint distribution $p(x_0,x_1,\dots,x_N)$ simplifies to $$p(x_0,x_1,\dots,x_N) = p(x_N \mid x_{N-1})p(x_{N-1} \mid x_{N-2})\cdots p(x_1 \mid x_0) p(x_0)$$ Therefore, we can write
\begin{align}
E_{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_{N-1}}[x_0] &= \int_{\mathbb R^n} \int_{\mathbb R^n} \cdots \int_{\mathbb R^n} x_0 p(x_0,x_1,\dots,x_N) \text{d}x_N \dots \text{d}x_1 \text{d}x_0 \\
&= \int_{\mathbb R^n} \int_{\mathbb R^n} \cdots \int_{\mathbb R^n} x_0 p(x_N \mid x_{N-1})p(x_{N-1} \mid x_{N-2})\cdots p(x_1 \mid x_0) p(x_0) \text{d}x_N \dots \text{d}x_1 \text{d}x_0 \\
&= \int_{\mathbb R^n} \int_{\mathbb R^n} \cdots \int_{\mathbb R^n} p(x_N \mid x_{N-1}) \text{d}x_N \dots p(x_1 \mid x_0) \text{d}x_1 x_0 p(x_0) \text{d}x_0
\end{align}
Then, the integrals $$\int_{\mathbb R^n} p(x_N \mid x_{N-1}) \text{d}x_N$$ and $$\int_{\mathbb R^n} p(x_{N-1} \mid x_{N-2}) \text{d}x_{N-1}$$ and so on evaluate to $1$, and so we are left with
\begin{align}
E_{x_0,x_1,\dots,x_{N-1}}[x_0] &= \int_{\mathbb R^n} \int_{\mathbb R^n} \cdots \int_{\mathbb R^n} p(x_N \mid x_{N-1}) \text{d}x_N \dots p(x_1 \mid x_0) \text{d}x_1 x_0 p(x_0) \text{d}x_0 \\
&= \int_{\mathbb R^n} x_0 p(x_0) \text{d}x_0 \\
&= E_{x_0}[x_0]
\end{align}
Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Why do you think it forms a Markov chain instead of being deterministic?  Imagine $A$ is a square matrix of all ones; then at each step, the first element of $x_{i+1}$ is just the sum of the elements of $x_i$, etc.  It's a matrix multiplication, not a transition matrix.

Comment: As written, $x_k = A^kx_0$, so $\mathbb{E}x_k = A^k\mathbb{E}x_0$

Comment: @jbowman What I mean by "the sequence $x_0 \to x_1 \to \cdots \to x_N$ forms a Markov chain" is that $x_{k}$ is conditionally independent of $x_{k-2}$ given $x_{k-1}$ for $k = 2,\dots,N-1$. Is there something wrong with saying so?

Comment: It's deterministic.  One could say that $x_{i+t} = x_i + 1$ is a Markov chain, but why?  There's no randomness in the transitions; describing multiplication and addition as a Markov chain adds nothing useful to the discussion.

Comment: @jbowman the reason I mentioned that it is a Markov chain is to justify the decomposition $$p(x_0,x_1,\dots,x_N) = p(x_N \mid x_{N-1})p(x_{N-1} \mid x_{N-2})\cdots p(x_1 \mid x_0) p(x_0)$$ and then to use this decomposition to prove my statement. I now see from @ThomasLumley’s answer that there a better way to prove this statement without mentioning that the sequence $\{x_k\}$ is a Markov chain.

Comment: Ah, I see... that's actually kind of clever, if roundabout!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the Markov property. For any two jointly defined random variables $X$ and $Y$,
$$E_X[X]=E_{X,Y}[X]$$
The marginal distribution of $X$ is just the distribution of $X$.
Now just take $X$ to be $X_0$ and $Y$ to be everything else.